# Sum works with 1000000, fails with 2000000 - bug?

Tags: warning-messages, summation

Consider the following:

```
Quit[]

lpf[n_] := If[PrimeQ[n], n, First@Last@FactorInteger[n]];

Timing@Sum[Max[lpf[k + 1], lpf[k^2 - k + 1]] - 1, {k, 1, 1000000}]
(* {15.5223, 35440069342409237} *)

Timing@Sum[Max[lpf[k + 1], lpf[k^2 - k + 1]] - 1, {k, 1, 2000000}]
(* FactorInteger::exact: Argument 1+k in FactorInteger[1+k] is not an exact number. *)
(* FactorInteger::exact: Argument 1-k+k^2 in FactorInteger[1-k+k^2] is not an exact number. *)
```

Am I missing something? Why should this fail? If I replace `Sum` with `Total@Table`, it does work. It also works if I replace `Sum` with `ParallelSum`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prevent [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html) from trying to do symbolic operations  by restricting `lpf` from evaluating unless its argument is numeric (specifically an [`Integer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integer.html)).

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

lpf[n_Integer] := If[PrimeQ[n], n, First@Last@FactorInteger[n]];

Timing@Sum[Max[lpf[k + 1], lpf[k^2 - k + 1]] - 1, {k, 1, 1000000}]

(* {14.8269, 35440069342409237} *)

Timing@Sum[Max[lpf[k + 1], lpf[k^2 - k + 1]] - 1, {k, 1, 2000000}]

(* {38.5197, 269533451410884183} *)
```

**EDIT:** Using your original definition,

```
Clear["Global`*"]

lpf[n_] := If[PrimeQ[n], n, First@Last@FactorInteger[n]];

Options[Sum, Method]

(* {Method -> Automatic} *)
```

For efficiency reasons with the `Method  ->  Automatic` it presumably has some threshold beyond which it will stop just using exhaustive enumeration and switch to first trying symbolic evaluation. As previously stated, the symbolic evaluation fails due to the definition of `lpf`. Specifying a `Method` that avoids any symbolic processing will avoid this.

```
Timing@Sum[Max[lpf[k + 1], lpf[k^2 - k + 1]] - 1, {k, 1, 2000000},
  Method -> "Procedural"]

(* {38.2143, 269533451410884183} *)
```

Comment: I don't understand. I'm feeding it an integer in any case. Why should this matter (and why does it matter only when `k` ranges up to 2000000?

Comment: The error message that you received indicates that at some point a symbolic evaluation was attempted. Presumably, at some point the algorithm decided that it needed to try and get a symbolic result for the “tail” of the summation. Why it choose to do that and at what point is immaterial. You just want to preclude that from occurring, hence the restriction on the argument to `lpf`.

Comment: I'll accept the answer, and thanks for the fix. but it still doesn't sit well with me. Still seems like a bug.

Comment: The issue should never have arisen since `lpf` cannot evaluate successfully unless its argument is an integer. So it’s argument should be restricted to integers whether or not it is used with `Sum`